# How to Set up Event Listeners with multiple views in a ListView item using the ViewHolder Pattern

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I have a web api that returns a list of user posts that includes the user's name, username, image, post, comments etc.

In my Android app, I have a ListView which contains these user posts. I used the ViewHolder patterns in the adapter to set this up.

Now inside every ListView item, I need to setup click listeners on the post, the userimage, name, comment etc. In the listener I need to get position of the ViewHolder so as to get the corresponding Object from my data. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you first inflate a view, in your adapter, where convertView == null, inflate your view row, then call findViewById on the new inflated view to get your child views and set up click listeners on them individually. A handy way to store the position that I use for my app is to get a view, and call setId() on the view, with the position. Then you can call getId() on the view when you need the position.

Answer (score 0):

You can also define your own listener(s) in your adapter with your post (or its id/position) for argument. For example:

```
public interface OnPostClickListener {
    void onUserImageClick(Post post);
    void onUserNameClick(Post post);
    ...
}

private OnPostClickListener mListener;

public void setOnPostClickListener(OnPostClickListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final Post post = getItem(position);
    ...
    holder.userImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(mListener != null)
                mListener.onUserImageClick(post);
        }
    });
    holder.userName.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(mListener != null)
                mListener.onUserNameClick(post);
        }
    });
    ...
}
```

And in your Activity:

```
mAdapter.setOnPostClickListener(new OnPostClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onUserImageClick(Post post) {
        // Do something
    }
    @Override
    public void onUserNameClick(Post post) {
        // Do something
    }
});
```